# How can I make the width of a div box to the width of its content?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a fixed right sidebar. This right sidebar right now has the width of 420px. But the width should be always the width of the content.

https://jsfiddle.net/nLdxcedv/10/

I tried it with `auto` but then the design of a fixed right side is not working anymore. Do you have any idea?

Here is the code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content" style="overflow-x:scroll">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>                
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

<tr> <td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum </td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum<br><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum </td><td> Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td></tr> <tr> <td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum </td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td> </td><td> Lorem ipsum</td><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>          

              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>



            <div id="sidebar">
                 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thread>
                <tbody>     

                <tr><th>Lorem ipsum<tr><th>Lorem ipsum  </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
<div id="cleared"></div>
```

And the css:

```
body{padding:40px;}
table{font-size:13px;white-space: nowrap;}
.container{padding:0px}



#content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 420px;
  margin-right: -420px;
}  
#wrapper {

  margin-right: 240px;
}
#sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 240px;
  margin-right: -240px;
}  
#cleared {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Tables for layout is a ***very*** old method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: And check datatables... http://datatables.net/

Comment: Thank you, I will look at it definitely, but for the table layout in this case, isn't there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Easily add fixed class name to table in sidebar and add this css:

```
.fixed {
 table-layout: fixed;
 width: auto;
}

<div id="sidebar">
<table class="fixed table table-striped table-bordered">
```

Comment: Hi I tried your solution, but something is not working. Here is your result: https://jsfiddle.net/nLdxcedv/14/

Comment: sorry just change the width to auto, so sorry

Comment: No, I guess you understood me wrong: I marked for you in pink what I need to has an auto width: https://jsfiddle.net/nLdxcedv/16/

Comment: I do not see a change unfortunately, what did you update?

Comment: This looks very well, thank you! Only if I make the content shorter the whole table is not 100% of the window: https://jsfiddle.net/pgfaomcg/1/ Do you know what I mean?

Comment: and if I make the content longer the table is wider: https://jsfiddle.net/pgfaomcg/2/

Comment: yes this what you wanted the table is depend on content for short text you can add min-width for example min-width:200px; to your css

Comment: well not the table should depend on its content, only the sidebar should depend on its content. The table should always be 100% of the page. But it is a very complicated layout, I am sorry :) But thank you, you already helped me

Comment: its better to make your #sidebar div overflow scrolable by adding overflow:scroll; and if you didnt like it refer to this link http://jsfiddle.net/2PbLy/